# Adjoint of a simple operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Take a smooth function $g \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{C})$, define the operator $A : L^2(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ by $Af :=  \Re \int_y f(x,y) \overline{g}(x,y) d y$. We label by $2,\mathbb{C}$ the scalar product of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{C})$ and by $1,\mathbb{R}$ the scalar product of $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$. I try to compute the adjoint of $A$, we have
\begin{align*}
  \left< \chi, Af \right>_{1,\mathbb{R}} = \Re \int_{x,y} f \overline{g} \chi d x d y = \left< A^*\chi, f \right>_{2,\mathbb{C}} = \Re \left<  g \chi, f \right>_{2,\mathbb{C}}.
 \end{align*}
We would like to say $A^* \chi = g(x,y) \chi(x)$ so $A^*$ would be a multiplication operator but there is the $\Re$ I don't know how to handle. Someone knows how to write $A^* \chi = ...$ with an expression which is independent from $f$ ?

Comment: There are two issues. The first is that $A$ is not well defined, let $g= g_1(x)\cdot g_2(y)$ with $g_1(x)$ having a singularity of the form $\dfrac 1{x^{0.3}}$ and $g_2$ just the characterstic function of the unit interval. Then $A(g)$ has a singularity of hte form $\dfrac1{x^{0.6}}$ which is not $L^2$. The second issue is that you are (if the map were well defined) looking at a real linear map between real and complex Hilbert spaces. Such maps don't have adjoints unless you throw away the complex structure on the second space and consider it only to be a real Hilbert space.

Comment: The problem on regularity is not an issue, we can take $g$ bounded. The real problem is the second one... I cannot drop the complex structure but I could consider the second space as a complex Hilbert, but I have to drop the Re and this is a problem for my situation...